# Django customize form radio buttons

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, forms

I've two radio buttons in my template for like/dislike and only either of them should be selected. I've the following code in my template and it works fine, but it looks really ugly and would like to customize it.

```
  <input type="radio" name="Like" value="Like">Like<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Like" value="Dislike">Dislike
```

I'm using the name and values in my views

```
 if request.POST.get('Like') == 'Like':
                con = UserContent(time=time, comment = comment, liked = True, disliked = False, doctor_id = doctor.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                doctor.likes += 1
                doctor.netlikes = doctor.likes - doctor.dislikes
                doctor.save()
                con.save()

            elif request.POST.get('Like') == 'Dislike':
                con = UserContent(time=time, comment = comment, liked = False, disliked = True,  doctor_id = doctor.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                doctor.dislikes +=1
                doctor.netlikes = doctor.likes - doctor.dislikes
                doctor.save()
                con.save()
```

I want the buttons in the template to be image buttons that look something like these

```
    <div class="like">
         <input type = "radio" name = "Like" value = "like" <img style="max-width: 100px;"src="/static/meddy1/images/like_option.png">
        </div>

        <div class="dislike">
           <input type = "radio" name = "Like" value = "Dislike" <img style="max-width: 100px;"src="/static/meddy1/images/dislike_option.png">
        </div>
```

I tried doing these but they don't work. I'm not sure if radio buttons are the best way to go with it. I just want only one of them to be selected since they are part of a form. Any idea how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do something like you want to do, I would use two buttons and I would send a $POST request to the server once the button was clicked...

So you have 2 buttons:

```
<style>
.vote{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.vote:hover{
    background-color:#666666;
    color:white;
}
</style>

<button class="vote" data-type="like">Like</button>
<button class="vote" data-type="dislike">Dislike</button>
```

Once any of them are clicked, this function sends the data to the server. Bare in mind that you need to send a csrf token to the server, otherwise you have a 403 error, unless you use @csrf_exempt in the django view, which I don't recommed.

```
$(".vote").click(function(){
    var vote = $(this).data('type');
    var token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
    var url = "your/url/"

    jQuery.post(url, { vote: vote , csrfmiddlewaretoken: token  } , function(data) {
      // ## deal with the response...
    });
});
```

On the server :

Include the csrf token to the view that renders the template with the buttons. I usually put everything in a params dictionary:

```
params = {}
params.update(csrf(request))
params['whatever'] = "another variable that you need to send to the template"
params['other']= "you get the point, right?"

## render the view with the params
## they become accessible on the template like this : {{ whatever}}

return render_to_response('your_template_name',params)
```

Use something like this in the view that deals with the POST

```
try:
    vote = request.POST['vote']
    ## do whatever you need with the vote value
except:
    ## deal with the exception here
```

### Putting it all together:

### Urls

```
url(r'^votes/$',  'app_name.views.votes', name='votes'),
```

### View

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

def votes(request):
    params = {}
    params.update(csrf(request))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ## Processing
        try:
            vote = request.POST['vote']
            ## do whatever you need
            return HttpResponse('Your vote was '+vote)
        except:
            return HttpResponse('There was an error')

    else:
        ##Displaying the initial view 
        return render_to_response('votes_template',params)
```

### Template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>

<style>
.vote{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.vote:hover{
    background-color:#666666;
    color:white;
}
</style>

<button class="vote" data-type="like">Like</button>
<button class="vote" data-type="dislike">Dislike</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vote").click(function(){
        var vote = $(this).data('type');
        var token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
        var url = "/votes/"

        jQuery.post(url, { vote: vote , csrfmiddlewaretoken: token  } , function(data) {
            alert(data)
        });
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Honestly, I can't do better than this. I've noticed you've been struggling with this for some days now, so this is my best effort to answer your question

Comment: Where should I put the second block of code? in my templates or views? What should I put for the URL ? The template is usercontent.html and the def usercontent view is in views.py.

Comment: If you mean the jquery funtion, It should be on the bottom of the template. Don't forget to add jquery to the page. also, when the view renders, you need to pass the csrf_token to the page as a parameter.. I'll update the answer to include this

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo mistake there which made the images not visible, try like this:

```
    <div class="dislike">
       <input type = "radio" name = "Like" value = "Dislike" ><img style="max-width: 100px;" src="/static/meddy1/images/like_option.png">
    </div>

    <div class="like">
       <input type = "radio" name = "Like" value = "Like" ><img style="max-width: 100px;" src="/static/meddy1/images/like_option.png">
    </div>
```